# Why does Medium use H3 tags in their articles while the Editor shows H1 when formatting?

Tags: html, seo, user-experience

Considering Medium is a highly specialised publishing platform, Im a bit curious to learn about their formatting choices. For starters, they seem to use H3 tags for first level heading in the markup when the editor presents the user with choices for H1 and H2. It is also interesting that they let users define multiple H1 headings within the same "section" (which is actually multiple h3's in practice). What is the thought process behind this? While I love the fact that they let users publish articles even without forcing for a heading in the presentation layout, what are the SEO implications for this product decision?

[image: Sample screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think there is any rule in google book which states that you can only use one H1 per page. take a look below:

> I always only use one H1 Element on any page. Google has recommended
>   this in the past. Many argue that having more than one H1 per page is
>   sensible in some instances (and HTML5 certainly allows for this). In
>   the end – it will depend entirely on the site you want to make and the
>   audience it serves. I think it is important to KEEP IMPLEMENTATION
>   CONSISTENT across your entire site to maximise usability.

http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/

In short Medium could get a slight seo boost if they followed the seo recommendations but they perhaps follow what suits their users best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still does not make it very clear as to why H3 instead of H1. Considering they want much more visibility for their articles it makes sense then to use multiple H1's itself  right?